# GET request in python not working

Tags: python, function, post, get, flask

I have this python code. And whenever i start the webbserver and go to the website i don't get the message " test ", just internal server error. How come? what am i doing wrong. Whenever i go to the website its a GET request right, so it should go into domain() function and give me the text " test "

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():

    if request.method == 'GET':
        domain()
    else:
        test()

def domain():
    return "test"

def test():
    data = request.get_json()
    with open("text.txt", "w") as text_file:
        pickle.dump(data, text_file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure the code is importing [`request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#accessing-request-data):

   ```
   from flask import request
   ```
2. The `hello` function does not return the return value of the `domain`, `test`. (same for `test` function):

   ```
   @app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def hello():
       if request.method == 'GET':
           return domain()
       else:
           return test()
   ```

Comment: Thanks it worked!, i had imported that i just didn't think i needed to show it but the return was the issue. Will accept it as answer as soon as i can! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not return anything that could be shown on the webpage. your `return "test"` is just returning the string and that string has no where to go.

You need something like:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('page.html', domain=domain())
```